# Parse xml into json

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I have xml data in the following format:

```xml
<inorganic>
    <name>iron</name>
    <display_color>
        <num>0</num>
        <num>7</num>
        <num>1</num>
    </display_color>
    <spec_heat>450</spec_heat>
    <melting_point>12768</melting_point>
</inorganic>
```

I am trying to convert it into json, like this:

```js
{
"iron": {
    "display_color": {
        "num": [
            "0",
            "7",
            "1"
        ]
    },
    "spec_heat": "450",
    "melting_point": "12768"
  }
}
```

However i have failed to find a way to do so with minimal effort (more than minimal would be tiring, my dataset is quite big).

Comment: What have you tried?  If you haven't tried anything [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML) is a good place to start.

Comment: Unless your XML data is huge, I see no benefit in this. Both xml and json are good formats for transmitting data. JS can parse both of them, and so can most/all server-side languages. I'm not saying it can't be done. Just, why?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I've used xml to json converters. However, as you can see, my xml data isn't isomorphic to my json data above.

Comment: @Jeffman Because the app that will use the data uses json.

Comment: You can try [fast xml parser](https://naturalintelligence.github.io/fast-xml-parser/) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);
$json = json_encode($xml);
```

or

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$json = json_encode($xml);
```